# How to align a table menu to an Banner

Tags: html, css

I've got a little problem doing rezise for my menu. I'm doing a banner that is 80% of the frame(is width) and I got a table just over the Banner that is my menu. Here my problem I don't know how i can fix the position to the right corner of the banner cause if i set his position to absolute it won't follow the banner when i shrink the frame. So im wondering if their a way that the table could follow the images instead of the frame.
Here my CSS code for the HTML Table:

```
border: 1px solid black;
border-color:Black;
display:none;
width:150px;
position:absolute;
left:1200px; 
vertical-align:top;
```

and here the banner:

```
  style="width: 80%; height: 175px; margin-left: 0px" align="middle" />
```

Here my code for my master page where the menu and the banner are contain:

```
    <%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style2
        {
           width:471px;
           background-size: 100%;
           background-position:center;

        }
        </style>
</head>
<body class="MainBody">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="MainForm">
    <div class="Header" runat="server" style="width:100%;">
        <div style="text-align:right; width:100%;" align="center">
            <table id="Tablessss";border="1"; 
                style="text-align:center; width:100%; table-layout:fixed; height: 94px;" 
                width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td id="td_Title" runat="server" valign="middle" class="style2"><asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                         <table id="TB_Conn"  runat="server"  class="Connection" align="right">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center"  class="Cells">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_User" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>


                                <td align="center"  class="Cells">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Access" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>

                                <td align="center" class="Cells">
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Disconnect" runat="server" text="D&eacute;connecter" 
                            Visible="true" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <img alt="" src="pharmacy-banner.jpg" 
                            style="width: 80%; height: 175px; margin-left: 0px" align="middle" />

                   </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;min-height:100%;height:auto !important;height:100%;">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="Footer" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lb_Developped" runat="server" Text="D&eacute;velopp&eacute; par EXA Systems Inc."></asp:Label><br />www.exainc.com</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

thx

Comment: To solve any problem like this we need to see both your CSS and HTML. Please ass it to your question.

Comment: @Diodeus - please fix your ass ;)

Comment: Damn, after all these years I still can't type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `float:right;`and try to show your code on jsfiddle.net like sites...

Comment: Yeah it's not quite what I want with it. My banner is not doing 100% of the page and I want my Table to follow the banner on top at the right end.